# Seaching for free SVN

Tags: android, ios, svn

Hi I am searching for free and good SVN tool that compatible with eclipse Android and xcode, it does not have to be same tool for both eclipse and xcode, maybe two different tools.

Comment: did u tried TortoiseSVN..it works in eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android:TortoiseSVN
iOS:Cornerstone/Versions